# How to get a loop in python to skip one iteration in the loop when it encounters an empty cell?

Tags: python, loops

I have a program that pretty much consists of a simple loop that goes through a bunch of numbers that are arranged in a column (among many other columns in the spreadsheet) and it consists of a bunch of if-statements that check if each number is within a particular range and based on which range it falls into, it will perform a specific task.

However, the problem is that, every now and then, some of the cells in the column will just contain a "-" symbol and won't have any numbers and the program just stops there, since it can't compare the dash sign to the ranges of numbers I'm making my if-statement comparisons to. What's the best way to just skip over these types of cells? I can't delete those cells because I've got like 100,000+ rows and there are other columns in the spreadsheet that are of use to me. I tried using the break and continue function but for some reason the program just doesn't read it as such.

Thanks!

```
 for x in range(1,1000):
    if value[x] == "-":
        break # I tried this with the continue function as well
```

Comment: You're looking for `continue`

Comment: [break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Can you show some background code. How the loop is being built?

Answer (score 3):

Use `continue`. For example:

```
for x in range(100):
    if 20 < x < 40:
        continue # skip to next iteration
    print(x)
```

That will print all numbers from 0 to 99, but skip the number if it is between 20 and 40.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in data:
    if i == "":
        continue # this will skip to the next iteration
    else:
        # do your normal stuff here
```

Comment: Hey, I tried that but for some reason, it's still not reading these blank cells correctly. Any ideas? Perhaps "" is not indicative of a blank cell?

Comment: @bioprogrammer I just put "" as a filler, I'm not sure the format that each line is read in. You'd have to paste the raw data that is read in so I could see an example.

Comment: Added above. Slight change, now instead of a blank cell, there's a "-" in the cell. I initially changed all the  "-" in those cells to blank cells, but I think it's easier ot deal with "-" in each of those cells than a blank cell.